# How to zoom into (i.e. focus on) a specific HTML element in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html, zoom

**Is it possible to focus on a specific HTML element in Chrome (or any of the other top browsers) so that the display window only renders the element and its inner HTML?**

I would prefer a solution that kept the original formatting of the element's contents, but resized the element to fit the display area.

I was unable to find such a feature in the F12 tools, however the way the inspect element tool works would be an ideal way to select the top-level element.

My web searches only turned up results for focusing the cursor on an element and zooming text in and out. Nothing that would cause the browser to essentially hide the outer HTML.